# Как изменить чтобы border bottom должен под текстом а не в центре текста?

Tags: html, css, scss, border

я написал коды 
 [image: busy]

```
.archive-article {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: $black;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed $grey;
    .thumbnail.small {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 120px;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqf9I.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

должны выглядеть как:

[image]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO - не место для агитация на выборы. И, конечно, отсутствие кода.

Comment: как могу исправить проблему?

Comment: Добавить разметку HTML.

Comment: Ну и если вас не затруднит, замените картинку на нейтральную, окей?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, добавив `overflow: hidden`.